# Is there a way to implement drag and drop for image upload in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, users

I amn looking for a way to inplement drag and drop image upload for  the profile image field and serveral other image fields as well for drupal 7 is there a module that is easy to use or an easy way to implement uploading per drag and drop in template.php?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using any of these modules :

1. [Drag & Drop Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload).

> This module provides a Drag & Drop Upload element and widgets for a
>   File and an Image fields.

2. [Plup](https://www.drupal.org/project/plup)

> This module allows you to modify your content types with a plup field
>   for drag and drop uploads.

3. [Drag'n'Drop Uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads)

> The Drag'n'Drop Uploads module adds the ability to drag an image from
>   your local filesystem, drop it onto a node body textarea and have the
>   file automatically uploaded and referenced in your node.

Comment: The OP is looking for this functionality for user images.

Comment: If possible I'd suggest he adds a field to the user object instead and turns off the built-in user image. But if he already has a populated database then he's faced with possibly integrating something like Plup himself or migrating the profile images to a field.